# Installing Fedora on external hard drive

Tags: fedora, boot, external-hdd

I am trying to shift to linux gradually, and I want to try Fedora. However, when I arrive at the place to install Fedora on my hard drive, the application could not detect my external hard drive but only my internal hard drives. I have no idea why that happened. May anyone give me a hand?

Comment: It is usually easier to install to an external drive, when you unplug, disconnect or otherwise disable the internal drive. It will also protect it from any damage (because of mistakes). Can you do that and are you willing to do that? (After installation you can plug the internal drive back in and select which drive to boot from via the temporary menu.)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. However, I’m trying to install it using my laptop, which I have no confidence nor any idea how in removing the internal drive (I’m those people who know almost nothing about computer hardwares, unfortunately). But thanks for your comment, at least I have some direction on what I can try.

Comment: There is a simpler way to install a Linux [installed] system into an external drive: I made a [compressed image of an installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS system that you extract and clone directly into an external drive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS) (the same method as is used to install an operating system into a Raspberry Pi system). You can try that first and then maybe pick up some tips from the [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step) and  links from it.

Comment: Ok, I’ll give it a shot. Thanks!